# Why does ant mappedresources seem to flatten paths to file names no matter what mapper is used

Tags: ant

I'm trying to do something fairly simple: take a path or dirset and extend each of its elements to get a new path.
For example, say I have a path that contains

```
c:\foo\plugins\com.foo.bar
c:\foo\plugins\com.baz.quux
```

I want to get a new path with:

```
c:\foo\plugins\com.foo.bar\src
c:\foo\plugins\com.baz.quux\src
```

I'm actually using a path based on a dirset for the first path, then using a `<mappedresources>` to get the second path, but the second path always ends up truncated like this:

```
com.foo.bar\src
com.baz.quux\src
```

To simplify for debugging, I removed the path and just stuck the dirset in a mapped resources, then I use a pathconvert macrodef for debug output.
I also replaced the globmapper I was using (for mapping * to */src) with an `<identitymapper>` just to see if it was the globmapper. It wasn't.

In a nutshell I have this:

```
<mappedresources id="src.resources">
  <dirset dir="c:\foo">
    <include name="com.*"/>
  </dirset>
  <identitymapper/>
</mappedresources>
```

Now when I dump this with path convert I get

```
com.foo.bar
com.baz.quux
```

(Again, this is debugging, in my original I use a globmapper and I get that same list but with "/src" appended - but I'm replacing the globmapper with an identitymapper)

Now, if replace the mappedresources with regular `<resources>`, I get the full path

```
<resources id="src.resources">
  <dirset dir="c:\foo">
    <include name="com.*"/>
  </dirset>
</resources>
```

Then I get the full paths when dumping:

```
c:\foo\plugins\com.foo.bar
c:\foo\plugins\com.baz.quux
```

Why?

The ant mapper documentation clearly shows examples of full paths being mapped to full paths with both the globmapper and the identity mapper, and only shows that the `<flatten>` mapper does something like this. So why is it happening here?

And failing this, is there some better way to get a path that contains all the elements of another path but extended with an extra directory like this?

One last note: I'm using these paths in a custom task, not in a `<copy>` or other task that takes mappers directly - I'm assuming this wouldn't occur directly in the task, but I haven't tested yet.

Comment: BTW: I never got an answer or found a solution, so I ended up coding my own custom Ant Type in Java for this